# How add actions to post on Facebook wall?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I use Facebook SDK for .NET I can post to users wall using app token.

Example of code where I create post:

```
        dynamic messagePost = new ExpandoObject();
        messagePost.picture = "http://cs608830..........jpg";
        messagePost.name = "A.......";
        messagePost.message = "I........ ";
        messagePost.link = "http://a.......";
        messagePost.req_perms = "publish_stream";
        messagePost.scope = "publish_stream";
        messagePost.actions =
            "[{\"name\": \"View on .....\",\"link\": \"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.........\"}]";
        messagePost.privacy = new
        {
            value = "SELF"
        };
```

And Its posts good , but I want to add second action:

```
   messagePost.actions =
            "[{\"name\": \"View on Play Market\",\"link\": \"https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.....\"},
              {\"name\": \"View on iTunes \",\"link\": \"https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/sla......\"}  ]";
```

But when I add secon action I get next error:

```
 (OAuthException - #100) (#100) actions should be a JSON-encoded dictionary with "name" and "link" keys
```

I am shure that I can add second action because in documentation https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/  I see next : 
actions - A list of available actions on the post (including commenting, liking, and an optional app-specified action)
So what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am shure that I can add second action

Then you are wrong.

> actions - A list of available actions on the post (including commenting, liking, and an optional app-specified action)

The first ones are the FB default actions – and there is *an optional app-specified action* – singular.